# How to ignore a java file when maven install

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have a @Service class where i'm caching some table data. I don't want those queries to run while building mvn install. Is there a way to ignore the file while building and it only execute when i start the server ?

It's a spring-boot application.

Comment: Are you saying you have test running during the build that is in some way executing live queries?

Comment: Actually i don't have any test cases but my application requirement is to cache few table records during server start up. I just don't want to execute that class/it's methods during build. it should just execute at server start up. @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        List<UserEntity> allUserRoleMappings = userRepository.findAll(); ....
    }

Comment: No code is actually executed during the build unless you have tests for it, or if you for some reason start up your application as part of the build.

Comment: I'm not sure. May be doing something wrong. my build section is: <build><plugins><plugin><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId><configuration><profiles><profile>local</profile></profiles></configuration><executions><execution><goals><goal>repackage</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>abcd</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

Comment: <dependency><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId><scope>test</scope></dependency>

Comment: My SpringBoot Test looks like this: RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
SpringBootTest
WebAppConfiguration
public class DccRolesApplicationTests {

 @Test
 public void contextLoads() {
 }
} Annotations have removed manually to post the comment.

Comment: Show us your expanded view of source code folders with file names visible.

Comment: @Shinchan, project structure is quite big to capture all files in single image. Could you explain little more, what exactly you are referring here?

Comment: We wonder on why the code is being executed when you do clean install. Ideally, it will happen when you have any unit tests or integration tests in your project. There is a possibility of having a plugin that gets invoked during the build phase and causing any code to be executed. So, double check he poms all all subprojects if any again.

Comment: @Shinchan. Thanks for pointing out. Actually i found that my SpringBootTest annotation is doing that and it's loading all the contexts during maven build, which is triggering the execution of all the beans.

Comment: Ahh ... You can add an answer yourself so that readers will benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is background of my issue. I have initialized the spring boot app from http://start.spring.io/ site, which actually adds dummy application test file with SpringBootTest annotation and default contextLoads() with Test annotation, with an intention to initialize and execute all test cases, which needs to initialize and execute all code base. In my opinion this is not required, as we can have respective Test classes per controller/manager, which will give more controlled environment to hook up your Test setups and executions.

I have removed the default application Test file and included respective test classes for code coverage and quality. This way my beans are not executed at server startup time rather build time.